# How to make Microsoft Teams launch my default browser instead of Edge?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-edge, microsoft-teams, links

I use FireFox as my daily browser. But when I use Microsoft Teams, when I click on a link in Chat, it always bring up Microsoft Edge. My default browser is set to Firefox. But Teams ignores it. Is there a way to get around it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Settings menu of the new Teams is actually on the Teams' upper-right corner of its window bar. There is a `...` left to the user status icon (I masked mine with a red dot).

[image]

Click on the `...` and you will see the `Settings` menu. And under `Files and links`, there is a section for `Links open preference` and you can choose "Default browser".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This was a default behaviour of 'classic' Teams. Upgrade if you can.

Your organization might still be managing the behaviour via policy, but if you're able to upgrade to the newer version of Teams, they've added a menu to select your preferred browser from either Edge or what you've set as your Default Browser: Settings  > Files and Links > Links open preference.

More info on the ways this behaviour can be controlled by you / your org can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/view-emails-and-web-links-in-browser).